# PDO uses correct value but inserts wrong value into database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, pdo

I have an AJAX call to my PHP file, which is able to retrieve and insert highscores from/in the database. The retrieving part works perfectly fine, but whenever I use the Insert part, weird things happen!

When I make the AJAX call, I add 2 parameters: `name` and `score`. When PDO executes, it always inserts 9 as the score. I have **no** clue why this happens and when I `echo` the `score` value before I insert it, it is the exact same as the one I gave as a parameter!

Can one of you guys please help me fix this issue?

My AJAX call:

```
function sendHighScore(name, score) {
    //name = string
    //score = decimal
    $.ajax({
        url: "../php/score_server.php",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            "action": "addScore",
            "name": name,
            "score": score
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        async: true
    });
};
```

My PHP File:

```
<?php

$user = "xxxx";
$pass = "xxxx";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; port=3307; dbname=Client', $user, $pass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'getScore') {
    $sqlGetScore = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM score ORDER BY score");
    if (!$sqlGetScore) {
        echo "\nPDO::errorInfo1():\n";
        print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    }
    $sqlGetScore->execute();
    $result = $sqlGetScore->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($result);
} else if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'addScore') {
    $name  = $_GET['name'];
    $score = $_GET['score'];
    echo "Before the prepare statement</br> ";

    var_dump($name, $score);
    $sqlAdd = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO score (name, score) VALUES (:name, :score)");
    if (!$sqlAdd) {
        echo "\nPDO::errorInfo1():\n";
        print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    }
    echo "</br>after the prepare statement, before the bindvalues</br> ";

    var_dump($name, $score);

    $sqlAdd->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sqlAdd->bindValue(":score", $score, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sqlAdd->execute();


    echo "</br>After the execute</br>";
    var_dump($name, $score);

}

?>
```

When I look in the database, score is always 9! Can someone see any errors in this script?

**edit**
Result after var_dumps:

[image: Result]

Might there be a (future) issue regarding score being a decimal number and me using PARAM_STR?

Comment: I copied the PHP code. It works fine for me. Can you put result of ``var_dump($name, $score)`` somewhere?

Comment: Can you also put your table definition? It looks like score column is to small to fit 12

Comment: Ah I see! I had `decimal(1,0)`. I changed it to `Decimal(10,1)` and it works fine! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the issue when I changed the `score` column to `DECIMAL(1,0)`

From MySQL Documentation [DECIMAL Data Type Characteristics](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) :

> DECIMAL columns in MySQL 5.1 do not permit values larger than the range implied by the column definition. For example, a DECIMAL(3,0) column supports a range of -999 to 999.

Please change the column definition of `score` like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `score` CHANGE `score` `score` INT(10) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I have changed it to `Decimal(10,1)`. That correct as well, right?

Comment: That works too. It depends on what values you put in it.

Comment: at least 1, and the maximum would probably be around 10000. I only need to have 1 decimal number

Comment: You can do ``DECIMAL(6,1) UNSIGNED`` then. Which will allow values between ``0`` and ``99999.9``